# Teradata LIKE for range for values - (regular expression?)

Tags: teradata, sql-like

In Teradata I need a condition to select only records:

- starting in numbers between 0 and 4
- followed by string ABCD
- followed by anything

I can use substring and it works. But this is not a nice piece of code.

```
SELECT
    '4ABCDXXX' AS T  
    , CASE WHEN   
        Cast (Substring (T, 1,1) AS SMALLINT) BETWEEN 0 AND 4  
        AND Substring (T, 2,4) = 'ABCD'
        THEN 'OK' ELSE 'NOK' END
```

I tried

```
LIKE '[0-4]ABCD%'
```

But this does not seem to be working...
How can this be elegantly achieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that Teradata supports the enhanced `LIKE` syntax which are you attempting.  But, in lieu of this, we can use `REGEXP_SIMILAR`:

```sql
SELECT
    '4ABCDXXX' AS T,
    CASE WHEN REGEXP_SIMILAR('4ABCDXXX', '^[0-4]ABCD.*$', 'c')
         THEN 'OK' ELSE 'NOK' END AS label
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks good. One detail - this matches only when the string has nothing after ABCD. Shall I want it so that anything can follow it would be:  
RegExp_Similar(T, '^[0-4]ABCD\w*', 'i'). Thanks, R.

Comment: @hro1979 Sure, I don't know this API very well.  I guess the pattern you want is `^[0-4]ABCD.*$` in this case.

Comment: Yes, for REGEXP_SIMILAR the pattern has to match the entire string, i.e. implicitly behaves as if you had ^ at the start and $ at the end whether you explicitly specify that or not.

Answer (score 0):

I've never been able to make negative lookaheads work in Teradata, so I would use two tests:

```
select 
'4ABCD123' as t,
case when 
  regexp_similar(t,'^[0-4]ABCD') = 1   -- starts with 0-4 followed by ABCD
  and  t like '%ABCD'                  -- does not end with ABCD
then 'nok' else 'ok' end,
```